# .Site.Data values are not accessible inside a range block

Tags: templates, scope, hugo, static-site

So I just noticed that when I try to access something from **.Site** itself inside a **range** block it returns as null/blank.

Here's an example:

```
<div class="row weekday">
  {{ .Site.Data.company.social_media.whatsapp }}
  {{ range $entry := sort .Site.Data.events "order" "asc" }}
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    {{ .Site.Data.company.social_media.whatsapp }}
    {{ partial "events_detail.html" (dict "entry" $entry) }}
  </div>
  {{ end }}
</div>
```

The first `.Site.Data.company.social_media.whatsapp` (before the range) renders a phone number.

The second `.Site.Data.company.social_media.whatsapp` (after the range) do not renders anything.

This same behavior happens in the partial **events_detail.html**. If I try to access the **.Site** from inside of the partial scope it renders a null. I also tried to pass it along on the `(dict ...)` but no lucky.

What Am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing how Hugo manage the scopes for the dot. You read a more in-depth explanation about this (and other important concepts) here:

https://regisphilibert.com/blog/2018/02/hugo-the-scope-the-context-and-the-dot/

In Resume is (extracted from the link above):

> The root context, the one available to you in your
> baseof.html and layouts will always be the Page context. Basically
> everything you need to build this page is in that dot. .Title,
> .Permalink, .Resources, you name it.
>
> Even your site’s informations is stored in the page context with .Site
> ready for the taking.
>
> But in Go Template the minute you step into a function you lose that
> context as your precious dot or context is replaced by the function’s
> own… dot.
>
> (...)
>
> Same goes here, once you’ve opened an iteration with range the context
> is the whatever item the cursor is pointing to at the moment. You will
> lose your page context in favor of the the range context.

```
{{ range .Data.Pages }}
    {{/* Here the dot is that one page 'at cursor'. */}} 
    {{ .Permalink }}
{{ end }}
```

> Luckily Hugo stores the root context of a template file in a $ so no
> matter how deeply nested you are within with or range, you can always
> retrieve the top context. In basic template file, it will generally be
> your page.

```
{{ with .Title }}
    {{/* Dot is .Title */}} 
    <h1>{{ . }}</h1>
    {{/* $ is the top level page */}} 
    <h3>From {{ $.Title }}</h3>
{{ end }}
```